# mongoose virtual populate for array

Tags: mongoose

I want to use mongoose virtual populate to get data but for nested arrays but is not working as expected  -

Following is my schema -

```
// schema for organisation structure
var OrganisationStructureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: Schema.ObjectId },
    Description: { type: String }        
});

// First nested array schema
var EmploymentRoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        _id: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        LocationId: { type: Schema.ObjectId }            
});

// Create the virtual to populate
EmploymentRoleSchema.virtual('Location', {
  ref: 'OrganisationStructure',
  localField: 'LocationId',
  foreignField: '_id'
});

// Parent object schema
var PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
   EmploymentRoles = [EmploymentRoleSchema]
});
```

**If I get person object like this it does not populate the virtual location property**

```
PersonelModel.findOne({_id: 1}).populate({path:    'EmploymentRoles.Location'}).exec();
```

**But if change nested schema from array to object as follows it works**

```
// Updated parent object schema change from array to object
var PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
   EmploymentRoles = {EmploymentRoleSchema}
});
```

**Now on running following code populate the location virtual property**

PersonelModel.findOne({_id: 1}).populate({path: 'EmploymentRoles.Location'}).exec();

Does populating a virtual not work with array properties?

The following articles seems to suggest it should work -

http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-virtual-populate.html

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html (Populate virtual section)

Thanks,